# Implement Android Search Interface with Jetpack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-search

i'm currently trying to implement in app search for my application and doing so with android jetpack
however i can't find a single resource on how to do so using the single activity principle.
Every official documentation only vaguely explains which steps are necessary.

Did any of you implement such a feature and how

thanks in advance

Comment: [Refer this](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup) It provide all options, you can refer to Activity if that you want to implement.

Comment: i've already checked this out, but it doesn't really explain how to implement it with the single activity principle